# ¿Cómo módificar el idioma del encabezado YAML de un documento Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, yaml

Quiero saber si es posible que el "Abstract" del encabezado de un R Markdown aparezca en español -como "Resumen", o la palabra que sea- cuando se imprime el documento a HTML. No el contenido en sí del "abstract", sino la propia palabra, que por defecto aparece en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
---
title: "Lorem ipsum"
author: Javier Blanco
output: html_document
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%m/%d/%Y')`"
abstract: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu sapien pulvinar, fringilla nisi eu, volutpat sem. Nulla sed libero vel nisi facilisis molestie quis sit amet risus."
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Mirando el código fuente del paquete [`rmarkdown`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown) particularmente el archivo [`default.html`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/f764a66d20768750ca6c2adac18f6830e665a9ca/inst/rmd/h/default.html#L538) que representa el template básico del output html, vemos que el texto "Abstract" esta fijo y no se obtiene de ninguna variable, por lo que deduzco que no es posible modificar éste texto, al menos de una forma "natural".

Pero, se puede jugar con un poco de código `css` para hacer que el  párrafo de la clase `abstract` no se muestre y se le reemplace el texto por el que quieras.  El truco es crear un `chunk` al comienzo de tu documento con la propiedad `results="asis"` y con el código `css` que produce lo mencionado:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
cat("
<style>
.abstract p{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.abstract p:after {
  visibility: visible;
  position: center;
  content: 'Resumen';
}
</style>
")
```
````

El código final quedaría así:

````
---
title: "Lorem ipsum"
author: "Javier Blanco"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%m/%d/%Y')`"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
abstract: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu sapien
  pulvinar, fringilla nisi eu, volutpat sem. Nulla sed libero vel nisi facilisis molestie
  quis sit amet risus.
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
cat("
<style>
.abstract p{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.abstract p:after {
  visibility: visible;
  position: center;
  content: 'Resumen';
}
</style>
")
```

## Ejemplo
````

Y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentarios:

- Esto técnicamente no es más que una "cocinada" (hack) para salir del paso
- Hay que rogar que no se use las clase `abstract` para alguna otra cosa
- Esto es solo para HTML, las otras salidas, corren por caminos totalmente distintos